# Restricting access by User in a related model's controller 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller where I'm doing some kind of funky selection. I have an Invitation table that belongs_to a User, and has_one User.

When destroying an invitation, I want the "has_one User" to be be doing the destroying, is in my controller I'm first getting an array of invitations the User has been invited on with:

```
def destroy
    @invitations = Invitation.find_by_recipient_email(current_user.email)
```

From this @invitations array, I want to do a find using the :id parameter. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
@invitations = Invitation.find_by_recipient_email(current_user.email)
    @invitation = @invitations.find(params[:id])
```

That way I can limit the invitations the user can access only to the ones they've been invited on (with the current_user method) and then select the specific invitation. I currently can't do this as .find does not work on an array.

Thanks for the help/pointers.

edit: sorry I made the post kind of confusing, here's some more info:

Here's my entire destroy method right now, I only want to delete one record:

```
def destroy
    @invitations = Invitation.find_by_recipient_email(current_user.email)
    @invitation = @invitations.find(params[:id])  

    if @invitation.destroy
      redirect_to invitations_path, :notice => "Declined invitation"
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
```

My Invitation object looks like:

```
Invitation(id: integer, list_id: integer, sender_id: integer, recipient_email: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Where send_id and recipient_email are two different users.

My invitation.rb:

```
belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  has_one :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
```

Maybe the issue is I would be calling something like current_users.invitations.find(params[:id]) and redo my invitation model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
invitatation_scope = Invitation.where(["recipient_email = ?",current_user.email])
@invitation =  invitation_scope.find(params[:id])
```

But you should use a before_filter:

```
before_filter :load_user_invitation, :only=>[:edit,:update,:destroy]

def load_user_invitation
  @invitation = Invitation.where(["recipient_email = ?",current_user.email]).find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`find` is an ActiveRecord method. You can use the Ruby enumerable method `select` to return an array of matching elements, and then get your invitation out of the array.

```
inv = @invitations.select { |i| i.id == params[:id] }
@inviation = inv.empty? ? nil : inv[0]
```